# How to reference the actual value in a one to many relation

Tags: sql, database, database-design, schema, relational-database

I have two tables, `pirates` and `bounties`.

| Pirate | Bounties |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| name | value |
| . | pirate_id |

One pirate can have a lot of bounties, but one bounty can have only one pirate. The issue is, I need to know what is the actual bounty, since I need to keep track of all previous bounties.

My solution was to create a cyclical reference with a deferent constraint `FK`, so my tables would be like this:

| Pirate | Bounties |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| name | value |
| bounty | pirate_id |

Or I could add one column to check if that bounty is the actual one:

| Pirate | Bounties |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| name | value |
| . | pirate_id |
| . | is_actual |

What would be the best approach? Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Each bounty is related to a single pirate by the `pirate_id` FK. Now, you say that you want each pirate to have another relationship to a single bounty probably called "current bounty"; if that's the case, your first solution would work (the column `bountie` or `bounty_id` in the first table). And as you say this FK will need to be deferrable as well. This is supported by PostgreSQL and Oracle only afaik.

Comment: yes, because i need to know what is the actual bountie of this pirate.

Comment: I edited my last table, I made a mistake and put is_actual on the wrong table

Comment: "since I need to keep track of all previous bounties" - Does that mean only the most recent bounty is "the current/actual" bounty?  Do you care about that history / order?  You could add a `timestamp` to the `bounties` table.  The current bounty is just the one per `pirate` with the latest `timestamp`.

Comment: I thought about getting the current bounty by the latest one added but I was afraid to run into issues in the future, also wouldn't be slow to search like this rather than have a direct reference to the current one? 
Yes, I do care about the other bounties and their order

Comment: You index the timestamp desc of the Bounty table (table names should be singular).  You add ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 to get the most recent bounty.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go this way. I guess I was overthinking about it being slow or not being the "most correct way", ty all for the help

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table that matches a pirate ID and a bounty ID.
This way you can change the rules over time (one pirate with several bounties or one bounty for several pirates, your choice). You gain more flexibility over time.

Especially useful if a bounty contains a lot of data that you don't want to duplicate when another pirate takes the same bounty aftewards. You will only create a row in the linkage table with two IDs.